# Kendo Grid - Group by column functionality is not displaying all in one page

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid with group by and pagination functionality. My grid page size is 10.

In kendo grid drag and drop any column for grouping, it show collapsible group row with number of  page size records. Its not showing all possible group items. I want to show all possible group item in one page. Is it possible in kendo grid?

Thanks